# Encoding text in RichTextBox from the WPF toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, utf-8, character-encoding

I'd like to write some text in a RichTextBox from the WPF toolkit with the degree (°) sign.

I simply tried

```
Section section = new Section();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
section.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
string str = string.Format("Temperature : {0:0.00}°C", temp);
text = new Run(str);
paragraph.Inlines.Add(text);
TemperatureText = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(section);
```

But the degree sign is replaced with a "?". I also tried to directly write the unicode `string.Format("Temperature : {0:0.00}\u00B0C", temp)` but it also failed.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks !

**[EDIT]**

I'm using the XamlFormatter for the RichTextBox

Comment: Check if there is a property LangOptions that you can play with.

Comment: Take a look at this page: It explains how to convert Unicode string to RTF-escaped strings:http://sketchpath.blogspot.com/2007/08/rtf-and-encoding.html. Also the last code example, with the \u00B0C, are you trying to escape to RTF? If yes, it is incorrect because you would have to put \\ into the escape sequence to retain one \ in the string at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Christoph. In the last code example, I'm not escaping anything, just use the unicode hex for the degree sign. The sign is well rendered in a text file, but not in the RichTextBox. Not sure to understand how the conversion you mention is relevant here...

Comment: I believe instead of escaping Unicode, you need to use RTF escape sequences. And that's where the linked article should help you, assuming my hunch is right.

Comment: Ok, but as I pointed out in the edit, I'm using the XamlFormatter and not the default RtfFormatter. Using the rtf escape sequence does not help.

Comment: @Christoph, your comment - it's GREAT! Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing your own formatter, that acts like the XAMLFormatter but using UTF8 Encoding:

```
public class MyXamlFormatter : ITextFormatter
{
    public string GetText( System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument document )
    {
      TextRange tr = new TextRange( document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd );
      using( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() )
      {
        tr.Save( ms, DataFormats.Xaml );
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
      }
    }

    public void SetText( System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument document, string text )
    {
      try
      {
        if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( text ) )
        {
          document.Blocks.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
          TextRange tr = new TextRange( document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd );
          using( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)))
          {
            tr.Load( ms, DataFormats.Xaml );
          }
        }
      }
      catch
      {
        throw new InvalidDataException( "Data provided is not in the correct Xaml format." );
      }
    }
}
```

So, in your XAML:

```
<wtk:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
    <myNameSpace:MyXamlFormatter/>
</wtk:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
```

It should works.